# Laptop only works after sticking in freezer, is there something inside it that I can replace?

Tags: laptop, motherboard, battery, acer-aspire

I have an Acer Aspire V5, and about two months ago it wouldn't turn on. It did not overheat, there were no power surges, and it wasn't plugged in overnight. I turned it off and in the morning, the power light blinked multiple times when pressed, but the computer wouldn't boot, it didn't matter whether the battery was in it or not, or whether it was plugged in, it just refused to turn on. Then the light stopped blinking and it was just a brick. So I took it to Best Buy where they told me the motherboard was fried and that I'd have to scrap it.

So, before I threw in the towel, I attempted the freezer method, I just stuck my entire laptop in the freezer, battery and all, and pulled it out two hours later, and it powered up perfectly fine no problems what so ever. . . fast forward two months later, same thing happened. The only thing that can get it to work is sticking it in the freezer for a few hours. I would really like for it to somehow last the semester. So is there anything inside it that I can replace? What exactly is the freezer fixing? I'm just worried one day the freezer won't fix it and then I'll be screwed.

Comment: Odd... Sounds to me like a bad connection or short somewhere, and cooling it likely caused the metal (or something) to contract enough to work. I would still put money on the motherboard is bad, trying to find this will be like searching for a needle in a haystack, could be any of a hundred things. Did you try just the battery in the freezer? Some laptops won't boot without a battery installed with a minimal charge in them, so it could still be a defective battery too.

Comment: Same thing I was thinking. Never heard of anyone sticking a whole system in a fridge before though

Comment: Even if you knew which exact component to replace, it would probably be impossible to do so.  Laptops aren't made to take apart and reassemble - at least not very easily.

Comment: The freezer thing is predicated on one of two assumptions: 1) solder joints have poor connection and the cold contracts the metal enough to force contact; 2) for hard drives, the platters contract enough to avoid "stiction". IMO, both of these are probably 98% bunk and 2% something very specific that ought not be generalized. Note that in car engines, cold temps actually contribute to starting problems (stiction), so... yeah.You probably will get the best results by transferring your disk to a new computer

Answer (score 0):

You can identify exactly which part or area of the laptop is bad by removing the case as much as possible and spraying it with canned air (computer dust cleaner). The compressed air in the can exits at below freezing temperature. This is an "old school" trouble shooting technique.

However, once you identify the offending part, you are unlikely to be able to fix the problem unless it is a memory stick or something similar.

Comment: I don't know where you live, but the canned air your talking about is ridiculously expensive here, like $10/per can, and we have to sign them out with justification (kind of stupid, but whatever). But the issue as stated in the comments is that even if the troublesome component is detected, the chances of repairing it in a laptop are very slim anyway. I won't down vote your answer, because in some ways it is technically correct, but it isn't very practical.

Comment: I appreciate your response. It does not seem to be very common now, but in years past memory or hard drives regularly had problems solved like this. He has a one in a 1000 chance - he can always hope! Home depot sells the cans for $3.50.